# More efficient way to associate newly created child with existing parent? (hasMany)

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models - `Channel` and `Message`. `Channel` has a `hasMany` association to `Message`; Message has a `belongsTo` association to `Channel`.

```
ChannelModel.hasMany(MessageModel);
MessageModel.belongsTo(ChannelModel);
```

Currently, I am creating a new `Message` (child) and am then getting the existing Channel's (parent's) `Message`s with `getMessages()`, followed by adding the new `Message` to the received array, before updating the `Channel`'s children  with `setMessages()`.

This may be more efficient if I could just `addMessages()`, however the Sequelize documentation states that `hasMany` associations create a `get` and `set` method but doesn't mention an `add` method, like `belongsToMany` has.

While creating a new child, is there a way to automatically associate it with an existing parent? Perhaps with an `includes` property in the object passed to `MessageModel.create()`? The Sequelize documentation seems to only have examples where everything is created from scratch (shows how to create a new parent via the parent model (not an existing one) while nesting multiple new children within the same statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well based on the associations you defined, your message object must have channel_id as a column... That field would be mandatory so you must have to pass it that to successfully create the message record?? You have a resolver and mutation set up for this?

Comment: Hmm, for referential integrity the foreign key can be either wholly null or a valid primary key in the parent. Creating a `Message` where `channelId` is null, then assigning a valid FK right after through the `get`/`set` workaround of sorts didn't throw any errors.

I haven't heard of resolvers or mutations, but I'm going to pass in a `channelId` attribute while creating each `Message`, that ought to work.

Comment: yeah it sounds like that should do the trick...  ok, you are not using graphql, i falsely assumed you were...

Comment: It worked, so, marking this as the answer. Hope that’s the correct procedure.